# app.js file stops working if it is edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am designing a webpage for a construction company using a template. the html file uses a js file called app.js. whenever i edit the js file, the whole html page becomes non-responsive as if the js file was never there to begin with. here is the code which exists in the app.js file.

```
//animate first team member
jQuery('#first-person').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery('#first-person').addClass("animated pulse");
    } else {
        jQuery('#first-person').removeClass("animated pulse");
    }
});

//animate sectond team member
jQuery('#second-person').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery('#second-person').addClass("animated pulse");
    } else {
        jQuery('#second-person').removeClass("animated pulse");
    }
});

//animate thrid team member
jQuery('#third-person').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery('#third-person').addClass("animated pulse");
    } else {
        jQuery('#third-person').removeClass("animated pulse");
    }
```

the file works fine with this pre-written script. but when i try to add the following line for a new id "fourth-person" i created in html file

```
 //animate fourth team member
 jQuery('#fourth-person').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery('#fourth-person').addClass("animated pulse");
    } else {
       jQuery('#fourth-person').removeClass("animated pulse");
    }
```

the html page becomes non-responsive. please tell me what might be the problem and a solution too if possible

Comment: Do you have a `#fourth-person` element in your HTML?

Comment: What's the error in console?

Comment: Did you check the console for syntax errors because that looks like a syntax error to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see at least two syntax problems, you are not closing the event binding for third-person and fourth-person elements. They should be like this:

```
//animate fourth team member
 jQuery('#fourth-person').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery('#fourth-person').addClass("animated pulse");
    } else {
       jQuery('#fourth-person').removeClass("animated pulse");
    }
 }); // <-- This is missing
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot.. can't believe i was stuck in a simple syntax problem. the code and js file is working fine:)

Comment: You're welcome! For future, just try and see what is logged in the browser console (F12). It will always give you some hints about the problem.